# What can be used to restrict navigation from panel to panel in a java cardlayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, cardlayout

I have two cards in a cardlayout and a button that allows one to go back and forth. How can I make the button inactive once it is clicked once so that the user can't go back to the previous card?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the button (in your action listener)

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a button inactive, do:

```
JButton b = new JButton("BUTTON");
b.setEnabled(false);
```

and the button will not accept clicks.

Answer (score 2):

[`JComponent#setEnabled(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 2):

You could add an event handler to the click event of the button and disable it with `button.setEnabled(false);` in the event handler.